# Library for python/perl to get chess eco code based on PGN format

Tags: classification, chess

I've got a large chess database in [PGN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation) (Portable Game Notation) format, but some games don't have tag related to an [ECO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopaedia_of_Chess_Openings) (Encyclopaedia of Chess Openings) code.

I'd like to update these tags in every game, so I have to find out an ECO code based on game moves.

Is there any library for python, perl, C++, Java or anything else, which provide this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

[Scid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shane%27s_Chess_Information_Database) can classify games using the standard [ECO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopaedia_of_Chess_Openings) code.

It's an open source project.